# Setting initial value of a select list generated through ng-repeat in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a select list from an associative array using ng-repeat.The ng-model of list is bound to a scope variable that has some initial value.The value of the options generated are the key of the array.

However, the list does not initialize with the value of the model.I thought it might have something to do with the asynchronous behaviour of ng-repeat, so i created a directive to capture the end of rendering and emit an event.This event is caught in the controller and is used to re-assign the value of the ng-model.

The event is caught correctly, but the update to the ng-model does not reflect.

If I attach a function to a button that updates the variable , it shows correctly in the list.

I know it is so because of the way ng-repeat works.How can i work around this automatically set the initial value after the list has been rendered.

Here is an example of my issue:

http://jsbin.com/gapemenova/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
    <h1 align='center'>
        {{value}}
   <select ng-model='value' >
    <option ng-repeat='(tid,groups) in templates' value='{{tid}}' on-last-repeat >{{tid}} </option>
</select>
      <button ng-click='refresh()' >Refresh</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  var app=angular.module('gobo',[]);

//Create A Directive To Detect The End Of ng-repeat cycle.
    app.directive('onLastRepeat',function(){
        return function(scope,element,attrs) {
            if(scope.$last) { setTimeout(function(){
                scope.$emit('onRepeatLast',element,attrs);
                },10);
                    }
        };
    });

app.controller('goboCtrl',function($scope){
            //Initial Value
                  $scope.value="2";
       $scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs){
                    $scope.value='3';
          alert($scope.value); });

   //Data Source For ng-repeat
    $scope.templates={};
    $scope.templates["1"]=[{"prop":"value1"}];
    $scope.templates["2"]=[{"prop":"value2"}];
    $scope.templates["3"]=[{"prop":"value3"}];

    $scope.refresh=function(){
            $scope.value="2";      
     };

}); //Controller ends
```

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't need to go to external site just to review the intiial problem. A demo is a great addition ... but should only be secondary to the code found here

Comment: Added. The behaviour in question would be difficult to understand without the demo though..

Comment: That's fine..it gives people the ability to review what you are doing..then decide if they want to further review a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this working demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bejaladuma/1/edit?html,js,output)

Simply change the `option` to:

```
<option ng-repeat='(tid,groups) in templates' value='{{tid}}' 
    ng-model="value" ng-selected="value === tid" on-last-repeat >{{tid}}</option>
```

Adding `ng-model` binds the selected value to `$scope.value`. Using `ng-selected` to update the selected item dynamically.

---

#### Explanations

Updating at the end of `ng-repeat` through `$on` is out of Angular `$digest` lifecycle, you need to run `$scope.$apply` to trigger a `$digest` cycle manually. Check [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gefisigahe/1/edit?html,js,output)

`ngClick` will trigger a `$scope.$apply` by default. Check `ngClick` definition in Angular 1.4.1 Line 23244:

```
scope.$apply(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shaojian. I am not really trying to find a solution by using ng-selected or ng-options. What I want is to figure out why capturing the end of ng-repeat and updating the model doesn't work, but updating it via some other function does!!

Comment: @DeveshSati Please check the `Explanations` in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ng-options` instead of using an `ng-repeat` to bind your options to your array. More on `ng-options`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jdmcnair. I am not really trying to find a solution by using ng-selected or ng-options. What I want is to figure out why capturing the end of ng-repeat and updating the model doesn't work, but updating it via some other function does!!